# Stop a DC Motor on a air flap recirculation car

Tags: dc-motor

i have some problems with a DC motor that rotate the flap from air recirculation in the car.
Problem: The ecu gives command when i press the recirculation button to the dc rotor ~10 sec, but the flap is closing in ~ 4,5 sec the rest of seconds the dc motor forces some plastic wheels from the ensemble => it's ruining in time.When i press again the air recirculation button the ECU gives reverse +/- to the dc motor to open or close the flap.

So before changing the broken things, i need an electric scheme to put it between ECU and DC motor when the flap go to the end, to fell the current growth and stop the DC motor.

DC motor voltage = 12v

Current value on free move = 60-70mA

The scheme must work +/- , -/+

I find on internet a scheme but i don't know if will work, i don't kown how to connect the circuit, i don't know the relay model.

[image]

Thank you and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sugest doing it this way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5xtl7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

here thereare limitswitched for both rotation directions and diodes that allow the motor to reverse back from the limit switch.